# psychopy: visual.Window() initialised with stereo=True fails with exception "pyglet.window.NoSuchConfigException"

Tags: pyglet, psychopy

I am new to psychopy and I have written a small piece of code to display fixation point. Everything works fine, if I do not set the option "stereo=True" or "stereo=False"
But the moment I set "stereo=True", it fails with exception
"stereo=True fails with exception "pyglet.window.NoSuchConfigException"
What am I missing here? Any help would be very appreciated.
I need to use this to supports quad buffers.

Complete error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "fixiation.py", line 3, in
>   
>       win = visual.Window([1920, 1080], screen=1, units='pix', fullscr=True, stereo=True)#monitor='DVI-I-1', units='pix',
>   fullscr=True) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psychopy/visual/window.py", line
>   325, in **init**
>       self._setupGL() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psychopy/visual/window.py", line
>   1425, in _setupGL
>       self._setupPyglet() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psychopy/visual/window.py", line
>   1286, in _setupPyglet
>       style=style) File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/window/xlib/**init**.py", line
>   474, in **init**
>       super(XlibWindow, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 645, in
>   __init__
>       config = screen.get_best_config(config) File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 291, in
>   get_best_config
>       raise NoSuchConfigException()
>   **pyglet.window.NoSuchConfigException Exception AttributeError: "'Window' object has no attribute 'useNativeGamma'" in > ignored**

Here is the sample code
from psychopy import visual, event

win = visual.Window([1920, 1080], screen=1, units='pix', fullscr=True, stereo=True)
fixation = visual.GratingStim(win=win, size=10, pos=[0,0], sf=0,  units='pix')

while True:
    fixation.draw()
    win.update()
    if len(event.getKeys()) >0:
        break
    event.clearEvents()

win.close()

Comment: What happens if you set `winType = 'pygame'` rather than `'pyglet'`? Do you know that your graphics card supports quad buffers?

Comment: Yes my graphics card supports quad buffers. And thanks having set WinType='pygame' helped. But I do not understand why pyglet has issues.

Comment: pygame can have all sorts of other limitations, so it might not be a great solution for you. Perhaps you should raise this at http://discourse.psychopy.org where you might get more useful feedback.

Comment: Thank you i have posted it in discourse.psychopy.org .